# Load & show foreach elements, wait a bit, load the next and so on

Tags: php, html

I got an iOS WebApp which is 100% HTML/PHP based (it's basically just a website) and it has an HTML list where I want to basically display a lot of JSON elements in lists via foreach. However the list appears to be so big, it crashes the entire site.

So in order to at least load a couple elements I've used >> if($num == 50) break; << to only show the first 50 foreach elements. But how can I load the first 50 elements, wait like 2 seconds and load another 50?

```
$data = json_decode(url_get_contents("LinkToJson"));

$num = 1;
foreach($data->data as $dat){
$num++;
echo '
<li> '. $dat->Name .' </li>';
if($num == 50) break;
} ?>
```

Really all I really need is a way to load & display the first 50 elements so Users can actually see the first couple foreach elements, wait a bit and load the next 50, wait a bit, load the next 50 and so on.

I hope anyone on here is able to somehow help me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: You would not do it at PHP level, you can accomplish this at iOS programming level. You would use a asynchronous call and pass $num as a parameter to PHP knows where it needs to break.

Comment: @Marco Could you please elaborate? I'd love to understand how this works and how I could find a solution to my problem

Comment: Can you tell how you are doing right now? You are using Swift, or Objective-C?

Comment: @Marco HTML only, it's a WebApp, basically just a website. It's all HTML / PHP / JS

Comment: Cordova or Xamarim?

Comment: @Marco I'm using iOS configuration profiles only. No Cordova, nothing. It's all plain HTML

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what you told me, it's pure html. This is just a very raw example, generalization to try to help you understand. The real magic will happen when you make asynchronous calls. Basically you will make a call for the PHP url, and at it's callback success (or setTimeInterval) you would the same call, only passing the start and end parameters so your PHP script knows what to skip and when stop.

```
$data = json_decode(url_get_contents("LinkToJson"));

$num = 1;
foreach($data->data as $dat) {
  $num++;

  if($num >= $REQUEST['start']) {
    continue;
  }

  if ($num == $REQUEST['end']) {
    break;
  }
  echo '<li> '. $dat->Name .' </li>';
}
```

Now you just need to make a ajax call and at success callback (or use setTimeout function to delay further call).

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // do something with this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "path-to-php-script&start=0&end=50", true);
xhttp.send();

setInterval(function () {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // do something with this.responseText;
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "path-to-php-script&start=50&end=100", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 2000)
```

Comment: You have repetitive chunks of code. Can't you simplify it by using just one function that takes the `start` and `end` integers as arguments?

Comment: Also, what is exactly `setTimeInterval` ? You mean `setInterval`?

Comment: I'm new to AJAX and don't really know how to implement that

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's was just for the purpose of example, like i said it's a very RAW EXAMPLE. You could do all the things you said and more.